# AutoIt Maximize current active screen

Tags: automation, autoit

Is it possible to run an AutoIt script that will simply maximize the current active window?

The window will already be opened, so no need to use the `Run()` function, just need to identify the currently selected screen and maximize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`WinSetState("[ACTIVE]", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinSetState.htm) will maximize the currently active window.

Comment: That's correct if you remove the second opening bracket (edited this for you). ;-) Additionaly if you want to resize the window over multiple displays, you'd have to use [`WinMove("[ACTIVE]", "", 0, 0, @DesktopWidth, @DesktopHeight)`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinMove.htm)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will maximize the window you select based on its title (the name of the window in the title bar).

```
WinSetState("WindowTitleGoesHere", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```